# filter joomla search result

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

Is there a way to filter menu items from a result search?

Comment: Do you mean that anything with a menu item would not show up in your search results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter anything in the output by customizing the search page template defaults in your "own" template with a template override (http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core).

The pages you can replace by adding them in your template are from

/components/com_search/views/search/tmpl

copy them into

/templates/yourtemplate/html/com_search/search

The search result page e.g. is displayed by : default_results.php

For yoomla 1.6 if you remove

```
        <?php if ($result->href) :?>
        <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_($result->href); ?>"<?php if ($result->browsernav == 1) :?> target="_blank"<?php endif;?>>
            <?php echo $this->escape($result->title);?>
        </a>
    <?php else:?>
        <?php echo $this->escape($result->title);?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

the title / menu item title is no longer displayed, just the text result.

You can make an conditional php statement to filter anything you like depending on the content of the search result and skip a single search result altogether. Just put your code directly behind the

```
<?php foreach($this->results as $result) : ?>
```

This is the loop for each single search result line. You can check for e.g. if ($result->href / title / whatever == something)  and then do a continue if this single result should be skipped.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! I implemented the filtering like you described, but this way I get mismatch with the number of results.  It is displayed by default_form.php: <?php echo $this->result; ?>. Do you know where this message is compiled?